# How do I create a unique array with Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I have code that looks like:

```
file = Nokogiri::XML(File.open('file.xml'))
test = file.xpath("//title") #all <title> elements in xml file
```

Then when I try:

```
puts test.uniq
```

I get the following error:

```
 undefined method `uniq' for #<Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet:0x000000011b8bf8>
```

Is `test` not an array? If it's not, how do I make it one?

Otherwise, how do I get only unique values from the `test` array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is test not an array? If it's not, how do I make it one?

`test` will be a [`NodeSet`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html):

```
Nokogiri::XML('<xml><foo/></xml>').xpath('//foo').class
=> Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet

foo = Nokogiri::XML('<xml><foo/></xml>').xpath('//foo')
=> [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x8109a674 name="foo">]

foo.is_a? Array
=> false

foo.is_a? Enumerable
=> true
```

To turn it into an array use `to_a`:

```
foo.respond_to? :to_a
=> true
```

However, that's not necessary because it also responds to `map`, `each`, and all the normal things we'd expect when iterating an Array because it includes [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html). `map`, by definition, automatically returns an array, so there's the conversion you wondered about in your comments and your question.

```
foo.methods.sort - Object.methods
=> [:%, :&, :+, :-, :/, :<<, :[], :add_class, :after, :all?, :any?, :at, :at_css, :at_xpath, :attr, :attribute, :before, :children, :chunk, :collect, :collect_concat, :count, :css, :cycle, :delete, :detect, :document, :document=, :drop, :drop_while, :each, :each_cons, :each_entry, :each_slice, :each_with_index, :each_with_object, :empty?, :entries, :filter, :find, :find_all, :find_index, :first, :flat_map, :grep, :group_by, :index, :inject, :inner_html, :inner_text, :last, :length, :map, :max, :max_by, :member?, :min, :min_by, :minmax, :minmax_by, :none?, :one?, :partition, :pop, :push, :reduce, :reject, :remove, :remove_attr, :remove_class, :reverse, :reverse_each, :search, :select, :set, :shift, :size, :slice, :slice_before, :sort, :sort_by, :take, :take_while, :text, :to_a, :to_ary, :to_html, :to_xhtml, :to_xml, :unlink, :wrap, :xpath, :zip, :|]
```

I suspect the reason `uniq` isn't implemented is it's very difficult to figure out how to test for uniqueness. A very simple tag, like:

```
<div class="foo" id="bar">
```

is functionally the same as:

```
<div id="bar" class="foo">
```

but the obvious `to_s` test will fail because they won't match a string equality test.

The tags would have to be normalized on the fly to put their parameters into the same order, then converted to strings, but what if the `class` parameter was `"foo1 foo2"` in the first tag and `"foo2 foo1"` in the second? Does the `uniq` code have to dive into specific parameters and reorder them? And, what if the tag is a container, like `div` is? Should the children of the node also be considered in the `uniq` test?

I think that's a can of worms most of us would back away from quickly, and those who'd jump into trying to define `uniq` would learn a very valuable lesson about rabbit holes. Instead, you are free to define `uniq` as fits your particular application, so it makes sense to you. I think that's a great design decision for Nokogiri's authors.

Comment: Eh, I was just 'splainin' how to fish to make myself happy, so it doesn't bother me. You know how it is, some people grab the first fish given instead of waiting around to see if they can catch something better.

Comment: I didn't see this response earlier, this has cleared up a lot of things for me. I've accepted this as the answer instead. Thanks Tin Man!

Answer (score 1):

please try -

```
puts test.map(&:text).uniq
```

See one example code to demonstrate how it works:

```
require "nokogiri"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<-EOF) 
<a class = "foo" href = "https://example.com"> Click here </a>
EOF

node = 2.times.map{|n| n = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new('title', doc); n.content = "xxx";n }
node # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x4637712 name="title" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x4636efc "xxx">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x4637690 name="title" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x4636218 "xxx">]>]


nodeset = Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet.new(doc,node)
nodeset # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x4637712 name="title" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x4636efc "xxx">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x4637690 name="title" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x4636218 "xxx">]>]

nodeset.map{|i| i.text }.uniq # => ["xxx"]
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, I still have multiple `<title>xxx</title>` that are the same.

Comment: Perfect! It works! If you could explain (in the answer) what `map(&:text)` does I'll select it as the right answer. Thanks!